# Is memmem available on mac?

Tags: c, macos

Can I safely use `memmem()` if I want it to also run on Mac?

I know it requires:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  `memmem` is available on MacOS.  See [the man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/memmem.3.html) for details.

You don't however need to `#define _GNU_SOURCE`.  That is specific to Linux.